# conditional tags for the output of a plugin

Tags: plugins, php, widgets, conditional-tags

I'm still quite a newbie developer so small problems like this bring me to a stand still from time to time.

I've basically built a custom plugin to display pdf images next to a link very basic I know, but my problem is I need the $title1 text to be a different colour on certain page templates so I'm trying to alter the output code with a conditional but it doesn't seem to be parsed in the browser.

the code now been parsed if the conditional only the .menu-widget div gets output on all page templates instead of .white replacing it allowing me to style it with css.

the IMAGES Constant is defined within functions.php file.

Here is my code

```
    class donor_pdf_plugin extends WP_Widget {

// Constructor
function donor_pdf_plugin() {
parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('Pdf footer description', 'donor_pdf_plugin'));
}

// Widget form creation
function form($instance) {

// Check values
if($instance) {
$link = esc_attr($instance['link']);
$link1 = esc_attr($instance['link1']);
$link2 = esc_attr($instance['link2']);
$link3 = esc_attr($instance['link3']);
$title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
$title1 = esc_attr($instance['title1']);
$title2 = esc_attr($instance['title2']);
$title3 = esc_attr($instance['title3']);
} else {
$link = '';
$link1 = '';
$link2 = '';
$link3 = '';
$title = '';
$title1 = '';
$title2 = '';
$title3 = '';
}
?>

       <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link'); ?>"><?php _e('Menu link', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
       </p>
       <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link1'); ?>"><?php _e('Menu link1', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link1'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('link1'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $link1; ?>" />
       </p>
       <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link2'); ?>"><?php _e('Menu link2', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link2'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('link2'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $link2; ?>" />
       </p>
       <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link3'); ?>"><?php _e('Menu link3', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link3'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('link3'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $link3; ?>" />
       </p>
       <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Menu title', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
       </p>
       <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title1'); ?>"><?php _e('Menu title1', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title1'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title1'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title1; ?>" />
       </p>
       <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title2'); ?>"><?php _e('Menu title2', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title2'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title2'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title2; ?>" />
       </p>
       <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title3'); ?>"><?php _e('Menu title3', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title3'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title3'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title3; ?>" />
       </p>





      <?php // end of widget form creation ?> 
<?php
}

// Widget update
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
$instance = $old_instance;
// Fields
$instance['link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['link']);
$instance['link1'] = strip_tags($new_instance['link1']);
$instance['link2'] = strip_tags($new_instance['link2']);
$instance['link3'] = strip_tags($new_instance['link3']);
$instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
$instance['title1'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title1']);
$instance['title2'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title2']);
$instance['title3'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title3']);

return $instance;
}

// Widget display
function widget($args, $instance) {
extract($args);
$link = $instance['link'];
$link1 = $instance['link1'];
$link2 = $instance['link2'];
$link3 = $instance['link3'];
$title = $instance['title'];
$title1 = $instance['title1'];
$title2 = $instance['title2'];
$title3 = $instance['title3'];



if(!is_home()) {
echo "<div class=\"menu-widget\">
<p><a href=\"$link\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\"> $title</a></p>
<p><a href=\"$link1\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\">$title1</span></a></p>
<p><a href=\"$link2\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\">$title2</a></p>
<p><a href=\"$link3\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\">$title3</a></p>
</div>";
} else {
echo "<div class=\"white\">
<p><a href=\"$link\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\"> $title</a></p>
<p><a href=\"$link1\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\">$title1</span></a></p>
<p><a href=\"$link2\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\">$title2</a></p>
<p><a href=\"$link3\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\">$title3</a></p>
</div>";

}
}
}


// Register widget
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("donor_pdf_plugin");'));
?>
```

the code not been parsed is this bit.

```
} else {
echo "<div class=\"white\">
<p><a href=\"$link\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\"> $title</a></p>
<p><a href=\"$link1\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\">$title1</span></a></p>
<p><a href=\"$link2\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\">$title2</a></p>
<p><a href=\"$link3\"><img src=\"" . IMAGES . "/pdf.png\"/><span class=\"pdf-description\">$title3</a></p>
</div>";

}
```

Comment: What isn't being parsed? Be specific. Where is the `IMAGES` constant set?

Comment: updated post - apologies.

Comment: Are you sure you need `is_home()` and not `is_front_page()` I.E. is your home page a static page?

Comment: Yeah my home page is a page template which is selected in the settings.

Comment: @Dannyw24 so `is_home` can't work for you, as I guessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is not wrong, probably the only problem is that you are using `is_home()` when you need `is_front_page`.

However, just for a tip, I want show how your code can be semplified a lot:

```
class donor_pdf_plugin extends WP_Widget {

  static $fields = array();

  // Constructor
  function donor_pdf_plugin() {
    self::$fields = array(
      'link' => __('Menu link', 'wp_widget_plugin'),
      'link1' => __('Menu link 1', 'wp_widget_plugin'),
      'link2' => __('Menu link 2', 'wp_widget_plugin'),
      'link3' => __('Menu link 3', 'wp_widget_plugin'),
      'title' => __('Menu title', 'wp_widget_plugin'),
      'title1' => __('Menu title 1', 'wp_widget_plugin'),
      'title2' => __('Menu title 2', 'wp_widget_plugin'),
      'title3' => __('Menu title 3', 'wp_widget_plugin'),
    );
    parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('Pdf footer description', 'donor_pdf_plugin'));
  }

  // Widget form creation
  function form($instance) {
    foreach ( self::$fields as $field => $label) {
      $value = isset($instance[$field]) ? esc_attr($instance[$field]) : '';
      $id = $this->get_field_id($field);
      printf( '<p><label for="%s">%s</label>', $id, esc_html($label) );
      $format = '<input class="widefat" id="%s" name="%s" type="text" value="%s"/></p>';
      printf( $format, $id, $this->get_field_name($field), esc_attr($value) );
    }
  }

  // Widget update
  function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    return array_map('sanitize_text_field', $new_instance);
  }

  // Widget display
  function widget($args, $instance) {
   $class = is_front_page() ? 'white' : 'menu-widget';
   printf('<div class="%s">', $class);
   $format = '<p><a href="%s"><img src="%s"/><span class="pdf-description">%s</a></p>';
   $icon = IMAGES . '/pdf.png';
   for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
     $u = $i == 0 ? '' : $i;
     if ( empty($instance['link' . $u]) || empty($instance['title' . $u]) ) continue;
     printf($format, esc_url($instance['link' . $u]), $icon, $instance['title' . $u]);
   }
   echo '</div>';
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks G.M, I read however that you should use is_home when its within a plugin this was directly on the codex - Thanks for updated code it looks alot better :)

Comment: @Dannyw24 Absolutely **No** matter if in a plugin or elsewhere: `is_home` is `true` **only** if your home page is **not** setted as a static page. `is_front_page` is `true` when home page is setted as a static page **and** when is setted to display last posts. So if you want to be sure something happen on site home page you have to use `is_front_page`, not `is_home`. Read [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

Comment: thanks that makes sense to me now. I'm still going through the code you've added quite new to the printf function but I understand the concept

Comment: @Dannyw24 there was an error. Try now, I've updated code.

Comment: when I add the php tags it brings up a server error. I'll try turning on debuging to find the error line.

Comment: {Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/nas/wp/www/cluster-1348/donordirection/wp-content/advanced-cache.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /nas/wp/www/cluster-1348/donordirection/wp-settings.php on line 58}

Comment: I'll style it and see if I can change it depending on the page then accept your awnser.

Comment: It works fantastic knowledge - and great explanation sure I'll learn alot from this code :D